# Does crystal charge stack?

Tags: league-of-legends

Can I get two charges of [crystal charge](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Skarner) when I ult someone inside of my crystal spires?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the wiki page that you linked says :

> While within range of a Crystal Spire controlled by his team, or while
>   an enemy is stunned with Fracture or suppressed with Impale

So it doesn't stack up. It's as soon as one of these three requirements is met, you gain X bonuses. Have multiple of these doesn't give more bonuses.